# Error Viewing Project Properties In .NET Core 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Any time I view a project's properties, in Visual Studio, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred trying to load the page.
COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
```

[image]

This error message displays in project properties when I click on Application, Build, or Build Events. It is happening on .NET Core applications only, and even displays on a brand new project. I have a coworker that is having the exact same problem as well. It also seems to be happening on .NET Core 1.1 apps.

**Project File:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

*Running Visual Studio 2017 (Version 12.3.5) and Resharper 2017.2.1*

*Have both x86 and x64 runtime and SDK installed*

Comment: What does your csproj look like?

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof I made an edit, and added the project file code. In this example, it's a new project. It's untouched.

Comment: Are you using GhostDoc? https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/138

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof No, I'm not using that. I will try removing all of my extensions one at a time, and see if it's an extension causing it.

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! See answer.

Comment: Good to hear that it's solved!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out this is happening because of a Veracode Visual Studio extension that I am using. If anyone else has this problem, I recommend disabling third party VS extensions, until you find one that might be causing it.

Somebody else reported this exact [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/138), using a different third party extension:

Comment: Creating a .Net Core 2.1 application, had same problem, fault was the Veracode Visual Studio extension.

Comment: @TomRegan why am I not surprised that they haven't fixed that yet...We are doing all of our static scans during our CI builds now, so luckily we don't really need the VS extension anymore. Would be nice to have more of a real-time scan though.